# How to install theme in wordpress on linux?

Tags: linux, wordpress

I am very new to wordpress. I want to know how to install a theme in wordpress on linux.

I am following this link but nothing is really working out:

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/install_themes.htm

Any lead is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *nothing is really working out*. Are you getting any error ? What issue you facing ?

Comment: when it comes to fill he credentials, I am not able to do that. Because I am working on an Amazon machine (ec2).

Comment: Check my answer. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way in which you can Disble the FTP Credentials for installing Plugins and Themes from backend

Just Add the following Code in `wp-config.php`

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Comment: Now I am getting a new error. `Downloading install package from https://wordpress.org/themes/download/nuntius.1.2.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Could not create directory.`

Comment: Make sure your WordPress project has enough permission.

Comment: how to do that. i have just installed wordpress on my server.

Comment: please help me out. I am struck here

Comment: `chmod -R /var/www/your-project-folder`.